# embed street view in fusion table info window without API or Java

Tags: google-fusion-tables, infowindow, google-street-view

I have a fusion table with street address in text, and I want to embed a small html street view image of that address for every location point, without myself using Java or Street View API (I'll admit, I have no idea how to use those).

So is there a way to do it using pre-existing websites that allow embedding or linking?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work in the InfoWindow…

I'd probably geocode the street address to get a latitude and longitude and then use the Streetview API to return the image.

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=300x300&location=' + <ADD LAT> + ',%20' + <ADD LONG> + '&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&sensor=false" />
```

Comment: Thanks. That works well with the address field alone. 
But instead of the fixed viewing angle, can there be a navigation control?

Comment: The above method renders a "small html street view image." To enable navigation control you'd no longer have a static image and you'd have to dive into the StreetView API me thinks.